# Non-degenerate distribution function: $F(ax+b)=F(cx+d)$ implies $a=c$ and $b=d$

Tags: distribution-theory, generalized-inverse

I'm currently stuck in a small part of a proof. Namely, if we have a non-degenerate [non-degenerate](/questions/tagged/non-degenerate) distribution function [distribution-theory](/questions/tagged/distribution-theory), $F$, where

$F(ax+b)=F(cx+d)$

is valid, then $a=c$ and $b=d$.

I was trying some things with the generalised inverse [generalized-inverse](/questions/tagged/generalized-inverse), but since we have not assumed that $F$ should be strictly increasing, then it did not lead me anywhere. I don't expect it to be very complicated, but now I'm all out of ideas.

Thank you all!

Comment: What is your definition of a non-degenerate distribution?